# $_REQUEST issue Undefined offset

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$ans=$_REQUEST['ans'];
$qes=$_REQUEST['qes'];
$ra=$_REQUEST['right_op'];
$count=0;
for($i=0; $i<count($ans); $i++)
{
    echo "Question".$qes[$i]"<br>";
    echo "Ans".$ans[$i]"<br>";
    echo "Right Option".$ra[$i]."<br>";
    if(isset($ans[$i]) == isset($ra[$i]))
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
?>
```

when submit the first page, then it shows

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\result.php on line 9

The first page where the data is posted.

```
<?php 
$i=1;
$x=0;
$y=0;
$z=0;

do{
  ?>
            <tr>
              <td width="30"></td>
              <td width="30" height="27"><?php echo "$i";?></td>
              <td width="493"><?php echo $row_question['question']; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="q_id[<?php// echo $y; ?>]" id="q_id" value="    <?php echo $row_question['q_id']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="qes[<?php echo $y; ?>]" id="qes" value="<?php     echo $row_question['question']; ?>" /><input name="right_op[<?php echo $z; ?>]"     type="hidden" id="right_op" value="<?php echo $row_question['right_op']; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td height="59" align="right"><h3>A)</h3>
                <h3>B)</h3>
                <h3>C)</h3>
                <h3>D)</h3></td>
              <td><h3>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $x; ?>]" value="A" id="ans_0"     />
                      <font color="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row_question['op_a']; ?></font>    </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $x; ?>]" value="B" id="ans_1"     />
                  <font color="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row_question['op_b']; ?></font>    </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $x; ?>]" value="C" id="ans_2"     />
                  <font color="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row_question['op_c']; ?></font>    </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                   <input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $x; ?>]" value="D" id="ans_3"     /> 
                  <font color="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row_question['op_d']; ?></font>    </label>
                <br />
              </h3></td>
             </tr>

<tr>
  <td height="17" colspan="3"><hr /></td>
    </tr><?php
    $i++; 
    $x++;
    $y++;
        $z++;
    } while ($row_question = mysql_fetch_assoc($question)); ?>
```

What is wrong in this code. Please tell me in details.
Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `isset()` before access

```
if (isset($ra[$i])  && isset($ans[$i]) && isset($qes[$i])){
  // your code
}
```

or

```
array_key_exists($i, $ra);
```

or

Comment: @SubhajitSarkar you have to do the same also with $ans and $ques

Comment: Please see the details of the first page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect all arrays to be the same size, which is not the case for `$ra` which is snorter than other arrays, therefore

```
 echo "Right Option".$ra[$i]."<br>";
```

causes the notice. Looks like you need to fix your `$ra` size.

Comment: Nonetheless, if there is a `$_REQUEST['right_op']` at all and it is an array, `$ra[0]` should not give any problems.

Comment: but he's not at $ra[0], he's at $ra[1]: "Undefined offset: 1"

Comment: @icedwater there's no rule an array has to have a 0 key in php

Comment: Thanks @cori, but where do you guys know `$i` is 1 and not 0?

Comment: Please see the first page details.

Answer (score 0):

`$ra` doesn't have as many members in the array as `$ans` does, so when you hit the 2nd iteration of the loop there's nothing in `$ra[1]` to display. You need to figure out why the length of `$ra` and `$ans` are different - without more information about what you're doing it's difficult for us to know.

As @Nikola indicates, you should always check to make sure there's something in the index you're accessing before trying to output it using `isset()`. Whether or not it's valid for there not to be something in `$ra[1]` when there is something in `$ans[1]` is something only you can answer.

Inferring a lot from your code, it looks as though $ra is intended to indicate the right answer. In that case there's only going to be one, so you should use `$ra[0]` instead of `$ra[$i]`, which will always show the first element in the $ra array. Of course I may be misinterpreting the intent of your code, so YMMV.

Comment: Please see the first page details.